# Perl script to download a file and check filetype

Tags: windows, perl, pdf, file-type

What I want to do is fairly  simple:
1) download a file from hard-coded URL (it will always stay the same)
2) check if the file really is a PDF (I thought that it is best to check the magic number %PDF)
3) if so, rename file and move to folder xy||if not, rename accordingly.

Note: this will be required to run on a Windows 7 system.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use LWP::Simple;
use POSIX qw( strftime );
use File::Copy;
use File::Type;

my $date = strftime("%m/%d/%Y", localtime);
my $url  = "http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options"
          ."/advanced-analytics/r-enterprise/ore-reference-manual-1882822.pdf"; 

my $dlfile = "Test.pdf";
my $resp = '';
my $srcdir = "C:\\pdfscripthome";
my $dest = "C:\\pdfdump";
my $old = "$srcdir/$dlfile";
$resp = getstore( $url, $dlfile );

sub CheckFileType {
    my $chkfile="$srcdir//Test.pdf";
    my $ft = File::Type->new();
    my $file_type = $ft->mime_type($chkfile);

    if ( $file_type eq 'application/pdf' ) {
        move( $old, $dest ) or die "Move $old -> $dest failed: $!";
    }
    else {
        rename ("//$srcdir/Test.pdf", "//$srcdir/NotAValidPDFFile.pdf" )
        || die ("Error in renaming");
    }
}

sub main{
    &CheckFileType();
}

&main;
```

What happens when I try to execute, is that nothing happens. Strangely, when I comment

```
use File::Type;
```

out, it downloads the file (of course the check doesn't happen).

I assume there is an  error somewhere in `sub CheckFileType { }` but I can't see it.

Comment: I haven't used perl to handle files, but in the top half of your script you're using backslashes, and in your sub you're using normal slashes in file paths. Are you sure that's how it works?

Comment: So far it worked in other scripts. As far as I understand, when you describe a full path (C:\\etc\etc.) you have to go with the windows format. Otherwise when instead you use variables for a path, it needs to be in Unix format.

Comment: @Bifrost and OP: You are both wrong about directory separators on Windows. As far as the Windows API is concerned, `"C:\\this\\that\\other"` and `"C:/this/that/other"` are one and the same. However, you have to be careful if the path is going to go through the shell or become a command line argument to another program. Use `File::Spec`, or, better yet, `Path::Class` for proper handling of paths.

Comment: You would do well to stop pretending that you are writing C and drop the `main` subroutine. You should also *never* call Perl subroutines using an ampersand `&`: that hasn't been necessary since Perl 4 twenty-two years ago. Now it just serves to provide a special way of calling subroutines that shouldn't be done in public places

Comment: @SinanÜnür: Surely you mean *Perl*, not *the WIndows API*? I have never been able to pass path strings that used forward slashes as separators to anything that could conceivably be called a Windows API function

Comment: @SinanÜnür: Please elaborate

Comment: @WurstMax: Note that, without the ampersand prefix, if you want to call subroutines prior to their definition, you must either provide a parameter list or declare the subroutine in advance. For instance, in this case you could have written just `main;` or `CheckFileType;` because the definitions appear first, but otherwise you would have had to write `main();` and `CheckFileType();` or predefine those subroutines with `sub main;` and `sub CheckFileType;`

Comment: @SinanÜnür: Please indulge me: I would like you to elaborate because I am ignorant and that common knowledge hasn't reached me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76552/discussion-between-borodin-and-sinan-unur).

Comment: @SinanÜnür: On the contrary I think *you* are being more than a trifle obnoxious. I went along with the SO interface because it pushed me to a chat window as soon as I started to type. If your time is so very precious then I wonder why you are spending it here, but I will remember in future that you prefer to be rude and elitist than to share your knowledge with a peer

Comment: @SinanÜnür: I'm afraid you are extremely rude and your pretensions are well beyond your station. Surely you see that, by adopting Stack Overflow's default post, I made a *request* and there were no *demands* *assumptions* or *entitlements* anywhere? And yet despite being unavailable for *private tutoring* you continue to post affected and self-important comments. Please go and do whatever else it is that is more important than good manners, and in the future I shall remember to disregard your input

Answer (score 2):

I successfully executed your Perl program (without changes) on Windows 7 with Strawberry Perl v5.20.2.

I was tempted to suggest several changes, but I decided instead to offer one simple change which will cause your program to complete successfully.

In the call to `mime_type()` on line 25, replace the argument `$chkfile` with `$dlfile`. This will cause `mime_type()` to look for the file stored during the call to `getstore()` on line 16, where `$dlfile` is passed as an argument specifying the filename.

Line 25 (original):

```
my $file_type = $ft->mime_type($chkfile);
```

Line 25 (incorporating suggested change):

```
my $file_type = $ft->mime_type($dlfile);
```

Without changes, your Perl program first stores the downloaded PDF file relative to the user's current working directory as the filename `.\Test.pdf`, then later expects to find the PDF file using the absolute path `C:\pdfscripthome\Test.pdf`.

If the user's current working directory is `C:\pdfscripthome` the program succeeds. In cases where the user's current working directory is not `C:\pdfscripthome`, the program fails because the argument passed in the call to `mime_type()` contains the absolute path `C:\pdfscripthome\Test.pdf`.

Comment: Hi thank you for your help. Sadly this still doesn't work on my machine. My perl version is 5.18 so I will update and try again. What happens is: DOS-window opens for 2 seconds and closes then.